# Como añadir un bot al grupo de telegram y cambiar la descripcion de bienvenida del bot?

Tags: telegram

He estado intentando y lo unico que he podido hacer es añadir un bot universal llamado UniversalBot que lo que hace es dar la bienvenida a los nuevos usuarios. Ahora lo que quería era crear un grupo pero que además de dar la beinvenida escriba un mensaje mio en particual.
¿Como podría hacerlo? Alguien podría orientarme o decirme los pasos para llevarlo a cabo?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el siguiente bot:

https://telegram.me/jh0ker_welcomebot.

Para instalarlo lo único que tienes que hacer es añadirlo como miembro y configurarlo con las siguientes opciones que te muestro. Estas opciones deben escribirse en el campo de texto, como si fueras a enviar un mensaje al grupo:

```
/help@jh0ker_welcomebot: Muestra la ayuda del bot.
/welcome@jh0ker_welcomebot: Configuras el mensaje automático de bienvenida a un usuario que entra en el grupo.
/goodbye@jh0ker_welcomebot: Configuras el mensaje automático de despedida a un usuario que sale del grupo.
/disable_goodbye@jh0ker_welcomebot: Inhabilita el mensaje de despedida. Interesante si solo quieres activar el mensaje de bienvenida.
/lock@jh0ker_welcomebot: Hace que solamente el administrador pueda cambiar los mensajes de bienvenida o despedida.
/unlock@jh0ker_welcomebot: Hace que cualquier miembro pueda cambiar los mensajes de bienvenida o despedida.
/quiet@jh0ker_welcomebot: Si un usuario no tiene permisos para utilizar el bot aparecerá un mensaje así indicándolo cada vez que intente usarlo. Esto puede ser molesto para el resto de usuarios. Con esta configuración los mensajes de aviso desaparecerán.
/unquiet@jh0ker_welcomebot: Se activan los mensajes de aviso para aquellos usuarios que no tienen permisos para usar el bot.
```

Así de fácil podrás hacer que cada vez que haya un nuevo miembro se le responda con un mensaje automático. También puedes establecer un mensaje de despedida. Cada uno administra sus grupos como quiere según las necesidades de la comunidad.

Suerte!